# Selectbox's width shrinks on tag deletion in Select2

Tags: jquery, select, width, jquery-select2

I use Select2 to make a tagging box. I added the following html code:

```
<select id="tags" multiple="">
    <option value="tag_1">Tag1</option>
    <option value="tag_2">Tag2</option>
    <option value="tag_3">Tag3</option>
</select>
```

And I used this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").select2({
        placeholder: "Select tag",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    });
});
```

The problem is: The text box has a normal width on first loading. After I inserted a tag it will be properly displayed. But if I click on backspace or click on the x of the tag to delete it, the text box shrinks in its witdh to around 5px. What am I doing wrong?
I also use twitter bootstrap, is there some dependency?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ..

Comment: have you tried setting the width??

Comment: sry, I can't create a fiddle which reproduces this problem. I already tried `minimumWidth: 200` inside the `select2()` function of the JS posted above.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple fix. Just change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").select2({
        placeholder: "Select tag",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        maximumSelectionSize: 1,
        width: '100%',
    });
});
```

You can also set your custom CSS by adding the following attribute:

```
containerCssClass: 'mySpecialClass'
```

And then have some custom CSS assigned to handle the width.

```
.mySpecialClass {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Either of those will work!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `width` option to the select2 initialization code.

```
$("#tags").select2({ width: '100%' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem but only with Bootstrap. I found this to work. These are the classes I found being generated by Select2.

```
#s2id_groupSelect, .select2-input, .select2-container, .select2-search-field, .select2-choices {
width: 358px;
}
```

Set width to whatever you need to.

Comment: Just Bootstrap's responsive grid does not allow setting a fixed width. So we need another solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem I searched more from google I don't find the correct solution, after some attempts today I solved my problem. The problem in the `.menu ul` menu from the `load-styles.php` within WordPress admin folder

The below code reduce the `input` text field within the select box to fit the select box and don't shrink after removing the tags.

Try this is work with me correctly

```
.menu ul {
    width: 97%;
}
```